# Can I set i3-3110m in socket PGA-989

Tags: processor-socket

My motherboard is broken on Lenovo G500S 59391747. I found a new board for my notebook with socket PFG-989. Can I use processor Intel Core i3-3110m with socket PFG-989?

Comment: The processor and the motherboard are two entirely different sockets not to mention the processor is soldered to the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

No.

> Sockets Supported: FCBGA1023, FCPGA988

From: https://ark.intel.com/products/65700/Intel-Core-i3-3110M-Processor-3M-Cache-2-40-GHz-